# How to implement a two-stage hierarchical model of time series data in R?

Tags: r, time-series, multilevel-analysis, epidemiology

I'm currently working with a data set that consists of a monthly case count for several sites, along with a number of site-specific covariates. We're trying to estimate the effect of one of them on the case-load (either in terms of numbers or a percent). At the moment, I've been using Peng and Dominici's *Statistical Methods for Environmental Epidemiology with R* as a reference for the approach I'm considering using.

For a single site, the idea is to fit a Poisson model with roughly the following form:

$$\log ({\mu _t}) = \alpha  + \beta {x_t} + \eta {z_t} + f(t) + {\varepsilon _t}$$

Where `mu` is the monthly case count, `beta` is the log-relative increase in cases due to a one unit increase in the variable of interest, `eta` is the vector of other measured covariates and f(t) is some sort of smoothed spline over time.

So far, I'm comfortable enough with this. My problem is implementing a hierarchical model that gives an estimate of the effect pulling from information from each site. Is there a particularly good way to approach this in R? A well-documented package for example? Is it sufficient to essentially treat this as a meta-analysis with each site as a "study" and use something like `metafor`? And is there a way to do it while modeling a site-specific covariate? The authors seem to be pushing for the use of a Bayesian hierarchical model, but the implementation of something like that is admittedly a bit of unexplored territory for me.

Comment: I can't offer a complete answer, but there is a book devoted to hierarchical models. Checkout Gelman, Hill http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/

Comment: If time series problems like endogeneity, unit roots and etc are not an issue, i.e. you have repeated measures data, I would try to use something like  `glmer` from package **lme4**.

Comment: @RobertKubrick my recollection is that Gelman's book does not have much of a focus on approaches to hierarchical time series. Can you recommend some resources that deal with the subject in more detail?

Comment: It's been a while, but I'm currently dealing with a very similar problem, where I would like to model time series data with a Bayesian structural time series where I also consider both fixed and mixed effects in the regression part.